# Make Matplotlib plot binary map starting from 1

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2d array and want to show it as a binary heatmap. I am using the following code snippet:

```
m = np.random.randint(1, 5, (5,5))
plt.imshow(m, cmap='binary')
```

However, in this way, the axis will be 0 to 4. Is there a way to change it to 1 to 5?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

```
plt.xticks(range(m.shape[1]), range(1, m.shape[1] + 1))
plt.yticks(range(m.shape[0]), range(1, m.shape[0] + 1))
```

[Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) about `plt.xticks`.

**EDIT**

In case of `seaborn`:

```
sns.heatmap(m, cmap='binary', xticklabels=range(1, m.shape[1] + 1), yticklabels=range(1, m.shape[0] + 1))
```

[Documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) about `seaborn.heatmap`.

Comment: This does not work with `sns.heatmap`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mr.cysl Check the EDIT addition. Please learn about the tools you use. Documentation on `seaborn.heatmap` is the first link when you search for `seaborn heatmap` in google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plotting function [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html), which allows you to specify the coordinates of your data, in place of `imshow`. Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

And here's the complete code that was used to produce the above images:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plotBinary(mmin=1, mmax=5):
    x = np.arange(mmin-1, mmax+2)
    cen = (x[:-1] + x[1:])/2
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(cen, cen)

    m = np.random.randint(mmin, mmax+1, X.shape)
    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, m, cmap='binary')

plotBinary()
plt.show()
plotBinary(3, 10)
plt.show()
```

#### Explanation of coordinates in `pcolormesh`

`pcolormesh` expects the `X` and `Y` coordinates to be passed as grids. Given that you have 1D lists `x` and `y` of your x and y coordinates, you can call `X,Y 
 = np.mesgrid(x, y)` to generate the the `X` and `Y` coordinate grids for you. This way you don't have to worry about the actual syntax of the coordinate grids, which is nice.

In the `plotBinary` function above, `cen` is a list of the box centers. This is also our list of both `x` and `y` coordinates, so the needed coordinate grids are generated by calling `np.meshgrid(cen, cen)` with `cen` as both args.